# How to batch-create posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bookmark controller which has the seven default RESTful actions.

I would like to have a form for batch bookmark creation.

It's going to have a textarea field where the user can enter URLs, one URL per line.

Upon submission, I would like to bulk-insert those URLs into the database.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to know without seeing your form, the field and the controller, but here we go.

```
 params[:urls].split("\n").each do |url|
   PostUrl.create(url: url)
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ryan. My bookmark controller model class is `Bookmark`. It has 3 fields. 1) url 2) Title 3) description.  Both title and description will be fetched and added by a background process. I'm still confused about how the routing works. It seems like I have to create two additional actions 1) batch_new 2) batch_create. Also I have to create `batch_new.html.erb` file. Could you explain about how the routing works?

Comment: @Giri I don't understand why you would need to have a `batch_create` action. Can you explain your thinking behind that?

Comment: I'm using `new` and `create` actions to create single bookmark. Thats why I would like to have `batch_new` and `batch_create` actions to handle bulk urls

Comment: @giri The routing is best explained by the Routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html